# Default back button background image of UIBarButtonItem appears over my custom

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

In the AppDelegate I'm setting custom back button background image with UIAppearence.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:highlightedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

In some cases after pushing view controller appears default back button background image over my custom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helped me to hide default image.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```